# Find a,b,c such that a polynomial divides another polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Find the real numbers  a, b, c,  such that  the polynomial          (X2 –1).(X–2)  divides the polynomial  X5–2X4–6X3+aX2+bX+c.

Can someone help me to do it ? I have no idea how to resolve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Notice that $1,-1$ and $2$ are roots of first polynomial which divde second.

So they are also roots of the second one...

Comment: Ok so we have f(x) = X5–2X4–6X3+aX2+bX+c and f(1)=f(2)=f(-1)=0                                            So we have a + b + c = -7 and a - b + c = -3  and 4a +2b + c = 48. And with that we can  find     a = 19   b = -2 and c = -24. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes...................

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=x^5-2x^4-6x^3+ax^2+bx+c$

By the converse of the factor theorem we know,

$f(1)=0$

$f(-1)=0$

$f(2)=0$

Therefore you will get 3 simultaneous equations to solve for a,b,c which can be simplified to be the following

$a+b+c=7$

$a-b+c=-3$

$4a+2b+c=48$

By solving them you get that $a=12,b=5,c=-10$